# SQL Oracle como extrair conteudo da tag xml em uma coluna blob

Tags: sql, oracle, xml

Há um xml que fica em uma coluna do tipo BLOB (no oracle) e preciso acessar uma determinada tag desse xml. Até então consigo recuperar a coluna dessa forma:

```
SELECT TRIM(UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2(DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(my_column_blob, 1024))) as tag_name_xml
FROM my_table
```

o retorno é assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

aqui deixo parte do conteudo do xml:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como faço para retornar o valor/conteudo da tag cUF ou cCT?
Gostaria da ajuda de pessoas com mais conhecimentos, por favor.